# pygame " event " object has no attribute "pos"

Tags: python, pygame

```
if event.type == pygame.FINGERDOWN:
    touch_pos = event.pos
```

When I run this code ,I get the error  'Event' object has no attribute 'pos' .

If I use pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN it works fine ,with no error.

How to solve this ,do you need to import something?

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
This code fails to run; even the critical variable, `event`, is undefined and undocumented.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. What is `event`, and why do you expect it to have a `pos` attribute?  Don't explain, *display* the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this table from https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html, FINGER~ events have an `x` and `y` attribute instead of a `pos` attribute.

```
AUDIODEVICEREMOVED which, iscapture
FINGERMOTION       touch_id, finger_id, x, y, dx, dy
FINGERDOWN         touch_id, finger_id, x, y, dx, dy
FINGERUP           touch_id, finger_id, x, y, dx, dy
MOUSEWHEEL         which, flipped, x, y
MULTIGESTURE       touch_id, x, y, pinched, rotated, num_fingers
TEXTEDITING        text, start, length
TEXTINPUT          text
WINDOWEVENT        event
```